# How to detect if file is downloading in c# or python

Tags: c#, python, file, download, directory

I have a mix python-C# code that scans list of directories and manipulate it files in a loop.

Sometime there is a download directly to the income directory and the program start manipulating the file before the download completed.

Is there any way to detect if the file finish downloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to detect if the file is done downloading is to compare file size. If you always keep a previous "snapshot" of the files in the current directory you will be able to see which files exist and which don't at a given moment in time. Once you see an new file you know that the file has started to download. From this point you can compare the file size of that file and once the previous file size is equal to the current file size you know the file has finished downloading. Each time you would take a new "snapshot" it would be, for example 1ms after the previous. This may not be simple to implement depending on your knowledge of python or C# but I think this algorithm would get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you download, you get file size. You can check file size before writing to file. If file size is same download size then allow writing.

Comment: I don't know when or if the download started, it's disconnected from me so I don't have the download size.

Comment: I think you are downloading from same program. If you dont have download size then I dont think is there any other way to find file is complete downloaded or not.